# Getting unexpected error: "Variable does not exist: ArticleType"

Tags: apex, unit-test

One of my test methods is returning the following error:

Case: CaseTriggerHandlerTest
Method: test_insertSingleWebCase
Error: "line -1, column -1: Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation: Class TestDataFactory : Variable does not exist: ArticleType"

[image]

While it's true that "ArticleType" doesn't exist in my TestDataFactory apex class, I don't reference that variable in my CaseTriggerHandlerTest class either. The "test_insertSingleWebCase" doesn't reference one either.

Here is the method that is failing in CaseTriggerHandlerTest:

```
    @isTest static void test_insertSingleWebCase() {
    // Mock up a test Web Case
    List<Case> testWebCases = TestDataFactory.createWebCase(1);
    System.debug('testWebCases.size: ' + testWebCases.size() + ' | ' + testWebCases);
    System.AssertEquals(testWebCases.size(), 1);
    
    Id origContactId = testWebCases[0].ContactId;
    String origSuppliedName = testWebCases[0].SuppliedName;
    insert testWebCases[0];
    
    // Query / Reload the Case so we can get the Contact ID, which was not initially provided but should auto update
    Case c = [SELECT Id, ContactId FROM Case WHERE Id = :testWebCases[0].Id];
    
    // Expected Behavior: Contact ID should not be NULL (because the Case Trigger has inserted a new contact)
    System.AssertNotEquals(c.ContactId, NULL);
    
    // Modify the SuppliedName, but add another case with the same SuppliedEmail. Verify you get same c.ContactId
    // (i.e., this should NOT have resulted in a second Contact being created)
    testWebCases = TestDataFactory.createWebCase(1); // get a new case
    testWebCases[0].SuppliedName = 'Surprise!';
    insert testWebCases[0];
    
    c = [SELECT Id, ContactId, SuppliedName FROM Case WHERE Id = :testWebCases[0].Id];
    
    System.AssertNotEquals (origContactId, c.ContactId);
    System.AssertNotEquals(origSuppliedName,c.SuppliedName);
}
```

Here is the TestDataFactory class evoked by that method:

```
public abstract class TestDataFactory {

// Account Creation
public static List<Account> createAccounts (Integer numberOfAccounts) {
    List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
    for (Integer i=0 ; i < numberOfAccounts ; i++) {
        Account testAccount = new Account(Name='Test Account' + i);
        accounts.add(testAccount);
    }
    return accounts;
}

// Contact Creation
public static List<Contact> createContacts (Account testAccount, Integer numberOfContacts) {
    List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
    for (Integer i=0; i < numberOfContacts; i++) {
        String strLastName = 'Jones'+i;
        String strEmail = strLastName+'@'+testAccount.Name+'.com';
        strEmail = strEmail.remove(' ');
        Contact testContact = new Contact(LastName=strLastName, AccountId=testAccount.Id, Email=strEmail);
        contacts.add(testContact);
    }
    return contacts;
}

// Web Case Creation
public static List<Case> createWebCase (Integer numberOfWebCases) {
    List<Case> testCases = new List<Case>();
    Map<String, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> recordTypes = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
    Id caseRecordType = recordTypes.get('1819 Case').getRecordTypeId();

    for (Integer i=0; i<numberOfWebCases; i++) {
        String strSuppliedName='Bob Jones'+i;
        String strSuppliedEmail='bob_jones'+i+'@randomdomain.com';
        
        Case testCase = new Case(Status = 'New', 
                                 Priority = 'Normal', 
                                 Origin = 'Email', 
                                 RecordTypeId = caseRecordType,
                                 SuppliedEmail = strSuppliedEmail, 
                                 SuppliedName = strSuppliedName,
                                 Subject='Test Case', 
                                 Description='This is a test. This is only a test.');
        testCases.add(testCase);
    }
    
    return testCases;
}
```

I think the issue is related to config/setup changes made in the org around Knowledge Articles, but I don't know why this code is generating errors since it doesn't create or use the "kav" Knowledge object in any way.

Thoughts?

Comment: I was able to save the factory and test class on my dev org. Have you tried running compile all classes, maybe that could point at the proper error message.

Comment: I assume this is happening when trying to deploy or push your metadata to your org. Are there other classes being pushed or deployed at the same time that could be contributing to this issue?